# How do I do a subquery using sqldf in r

Tags: sql, r, sqldf

How do i do a subquery using sqldf in r

```
library(sqldf)
data(mtcars)

sqldf("select * from mtcars where mpg>avg(mpg)")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As standard SQL, you want a subquery like this:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select *
       from mtcars
       where mpg > (
         select avg(mpg)
         from mtcars
       )"
)
```